# Chocolatey - Optional Packages with user-confirmation in packages.config

Tags: chocolatey, windows-package-manager

Is there a way to specify an optional package in `packages.config` file which enables user confirmation before installing an application?

For Example, If I have 3 PC's, I would like to install "VSCode" in 2 of them, but not in the 3rd PC. So, to help with this, is there a way for me to optinoally mention or choose which apps to be "installed" or "not installed" during batch installation from packages.config?

If not in Chocolatey, is there a similar feature in other Windows Package managers?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is a process of [Configuration Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_management), not package installation. You should use a tool such as [Chef](https://docs.chef.io/platform_overview/), [SaltStack](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/getstarted/), [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/overview/how-ansible-works), [SCCM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/services-hub/health/getting-started-sccm), [DSC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dsc/getting-started/winGettingStarted?view=powershell-7.1), etc. to define requirements for your infrastructure. You would define packages to install on guests based on those requirements using configuration management tools, but trying to use a package to handle this for you is really against what a package is meant to define, which is a single piece of software and optionally a collection of dependencies to install based on the requirements of the original package.

Yes, you could cobble something together to do this with [Chocolatey](https://adamtheautomator.com/create-chocolatey-package/) and [package parameters](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/choco/commands/install#options-and-switches) (search `--package-parameters` to see the argument to pass in for custom parameters defined in a package you create) or any other package format but it is not a cohesive solution. I am not aware of a way to define this behavior using `packages.config`, either. I highly recommend against taking this approach and use an appropriate tool for configuration management.